# sql statement that gives me entities that contanins 1.value AND 2.value from one column

Tags: sql

i my table looks like this:

```
Column1|Column2  
1      |a  
1      |b  
1      |c  
2      |a  
3      |b  
4      |a  
4      |b
```

...

What I need is to write sql statetment to get all entities from column1 which has values a AND b in column2.
So in this case result will be: 1,4

Thx in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select column1 from your_table
group by column1
having 
max(case when column2='a' then 1 else 0 end)+
max(case when column2='b' then 1 else 0 end)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table T
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'A' FROM Table Ta
    WHERE T.column1 = Ta.column1
    AND Ta.column2 = 'a'
)
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 'B' FROM Table Tb
    WHERE T.column1 = Tb.column1
    AND Tb.column2 = 'b'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join:

```
 select column1
 from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on(t1.column1 = t2.column1)
 where t1.column1 = 'a'
   and t2.column1 = 'b'
```